# Story behind Derived to MatrixBase<Derived> conversion

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

What happens when you pass a matrix object into a function as a MatrixBase reference? I do not get what really happens behind the scenes.

An example function code would be:

```
#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <iostream>

using namspace Eigen;

template <typename Derived>
void print_size(const MatrixBase<Derived>& b)
{
  std::cout << "size (rows, cols): " << b.size() << " (" << b.rows()
            << ", " << b.cols() << ")" << std::endl;
  std::cout << sizeof(b) << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    Matrix<float, 2, 2> m;
    m << 0.0, 0.1,
         0.2, 0.3;

    print_size(m);
    std::cout << sizeof(m) << std::endl;
}
```

It gives the following output:

```
size (rows, cols): 4 (2, 2)
1
16
```

Where does the 16 vs. 1 difference come from?

And also why would a conversion be necessary?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Oh wait, brain fart! I don't understand how `sizeof` of a reference could ever be 1. This question is more interesting than I initially thought. I thought initially there was some kind of implicit type conversion going on, but `sizeof` for a reference should still be analogical to doing sizeof on a pointer.

Comment: @TeamUpvote - sizeof  for reference is just sizeof for referenced type. Add to `main()` `std::cout << sizeof(MatrixBase<float>) << std::endl;` and you'll see why all of this is as it is

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`sizeof` is evaluated at compile time, so it is concerned with the declared (static) type of objects. `b` is of type `MatrixBase<Derived>` (ignoring the reference, just like `sizeof` does), which is most likely an empty base class, and hence has size 1.

`m`, on the other hand, is of type `Matrix<float, 2, 2>`, which apparently has size 16 on your platform.

I've created a [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/66fecd496c09b2df) demonstrating this behaviour of `sizeof`.

Comment: The part about ignoring the reference I didn't quite get. I thought `sizeof(reference_type)` would be analogical to `sizeof(pointer)`, like 4 bytes on 32-bit or 8 bytes on 64-bit. It felt like there was slicing going on but I'm still confused why `sizeof` for a reference type could ever be 1 byte.

Comment: @TeamUpvote sizeof applied to a reference returns size of the referenced type. That is just how it is defined.

Comment: @TeamUpvote When `sizeof` is applied to a reference or reference type, it gives the size of the referenced type.

Comment: Wow! I always thought it was synonymous with doing `sizeof` on a pointer. Thanks for teaching me something new!

Comment: But, sizeof(MatrixBase <Matrix<float, 2, 2>>) also gives 1. Even though the reference is removed.

Comment: @OnurA Exactly. As the answer says, `sizeof` ignores references (that is, it gives the exact same value for `T` and for `T&`, for any `T`).

Comment: @Angew Actually I had a super brain fart there because that makes total sense -- just as `sizeof(*ptr)` would give sizeof a pointee type, `sizeof(ref)` makes sense to give size of referenced type! I've been working in C at my workplace lately and have forgotten some basics of C++.

Comment: @OnurA I had to look up the `Eigen::Matrix` docs real quick but it looks like it has 6 different template parameters, not 3. The other 3 are apparently optional but you'd probably need to pass them in to avoid the implicit conversion.

Comment: @TeamUpvote what I actually wanted to find out was, what happens when the argument is passed. Why would the conversion necessary in that case?

Comment: @OnurA Mismatching types combined with some kind of conversion operator or implicit constructor. I would have thought you could omit the optional template parameters though. I'm not 100% sure why it implicitly converts in this case if you at least specify the 3 template parameters, but only explanation with different `sizeof` values given these answers.

Comment: @OnurA The only implicit conversion going on is the derived-to-base *reference* conversion on binding. In reality, it's just the case of static vs. dynamic type. See the live example I've added to the answer.

Comment: I need to get some new glasses because the whole time I failed to notice that `MatrixBase` was used in the function while `Matrix` was used by the caller. Thought `Matrix` was used for both. I'm reaching that age where I'm neither near-sighted nor far-sighted. I just can't see anything unless it's at a perfect distance. If it's too far I can't see it, if it's too close I can't see it. Doh!

Comment: I can confirm your assumption that `MatrixBase<Derived>` is an empty base class. Eigen uses the CRTP here. If you want the actual size, you can write either `sizeof(Derived)` or `sizeof b.derived()`

Answer (score 3):

`sizeof` works on compile time types. See [sizeof](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof)

> When applied to an expression, sizeof does not evaluate the
>   expression, and even if the expression designates a polymorphic
>   object, the result is the size of the static type of the expression.

This means that you get the size of `MatrixBase<Derived>` regardless of what type the instance is.

The expression `sizeof(b)` is exactly the same as if you wrote `sizeof(MatrixBase<Derived>)`.